# Makefile cache problem

Tags: bash, make

I am not sure about the problem so apologies if the title is not appropriate.

I implemented the following Makefile rule:

```
check-vendor:
    @$(eval HASH1 = $(shell find vendor -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 shasum | md5 #hash1))
    go mod vendor
    @$(eval HASH2 = $(shell find vendor -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 shasum | md5))
```

Basically, I run `md5` command on a `vendor` folder two times. In between, the `go mod vendor` is a command that may update the `vendor` folder.

Yet, this rule doesn't work. Everytime (regardless if `go mod vendor` updated the folder or not) `HASH1` is always equals to `HASH2`.

If I port it in a bash script it does work though:

```
#!/bin/bash
HASH1="$(find vendor -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 shasum | md5)"
go mod vendor
HASH2="$(find vendor -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 shasum | md5)"
if [ "$HASH1" = "$HASH2" ]; then
    exit 0
else
    echo "vendor folder is out of sync"
    exit 1
fi
```

So, what is going on with the Makefile rule? It looks like there is a cache or a refresh problem. I'm not sure...
Any idea?

Cheers

Comment: **Please [edit] your question** and add some background information about what you want to achieve. I guess you want to do something in your makefile if `go mod vendor` has modified any file in `vendor`, right? How do you use the variables in your makefile? There might be a different solution like updating a hash file only if the hash value changed or if it didn't exist. This would allow using normal dependency rules.

Comment: I want to exit 1 if the hashes are not identical after having run `go mod vendor`

Comment: Please add this to the question. Do I understand right that you want to make the rule fail it the variables don't match? This may not work if you run `make` again if the first run modified the files and the second run doesn't do this again. And what do you want to do if the variables match?

Comment: Well, nothing. I just want to exit with an error if the hashes are not identical.

Comment: And if you do nothing, the command will also exit. What will be the difference? Your question looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make variables aren’t evaluated as the shell commands are run, they are evaluated before, so both hashes are calculated before `go mod vendor` runs.

You should write the hash evaluations as command lines in the recipe, not Make variables:

```make
check-vendor:
        HASH1="$$(find vendor -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 shasum | md5)" && \
        go mod vendor && \
        HASH2="$$(find vendor -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 shasum | md5)" && \
        [ "$$HASH1" = "$$HASH2" ]
```

Alternatively, checking `vendor/modules.txt` might be sufficient; in Go projects I work on, I use this (which only checks whether `go mod vendor` is *needed*, not whether it makes any changes):

```make
vendor/modules.txt: go.mod
        go mod vendor
```

Hashing `vendor/modules.txt` would be sufficient for your `check-vendor`.

Comment: It does not check only `vendor/modules.txt`. It does the checksum on all the different files.

Comment: I know your rule doesn’t only check `modules.txt`. I’m saying it might be enough for you to only check `modules.txt`.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread it. Good to know thanks.
I did test it though and the rule is returning OK in any case...

Comment: Make executes every command of the recipe in a separate shell, so the variables don't propagate from one command to the next. You would have to use `HASH1=something; go mod vendor ; HASH2=something; [ "$$HASH1" = "$$HASH2 ]`. You can use escaped newlines if you want to have separate lines.

Comment: @Bodo oops, yes, I left that part out; I’ve added `&& \` at the end of every line (which provides the usual “stop on first failure” behaviour of Make).

Comment: Thank you very much @StephenKitt :)

Comment: You’re welcome @RickyMartin92! Do think about the `vendor/modules.txt: go.mod` approach, IMO it’s better-suited to how Make works. (Of course, all this depends on exactly what you’re using `check-vendor` for.)